# What is with the shift in Total Eclipse after episode 2?

Tags: muv-luv

I started watching Total Eclipse, which I understand is part of Muv-Luv, but I am unfamiliar with. After episode 2, it seems like the whole tone of the show shifts. Is there some background into what's going on? The first two episodes reminded me a bit of Blue Gender, but after reaching episode 9 it seems like that was totally left behind.

Comment: I believe its split in 2 parts. Where the second part is a alternative universe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not played the visual novels and have not seen any other MuvLuv content, so I can only judge from the anime series. In this series, the two first episodes focus on the background of Yui. You basically witness what she has experienced when she was younger, and then the shift focuses on the 'current day' situation, where Yui is one of the two lead protagonists. Further down the series she reveals some of her background which is consistent with the first two episodes.

Comment: It appears I just need to watch further to see it all come together then. It feels pretty jarring to me but we'll see how things wrap up.

Comment: @Travis This is reason why many people don't like TE. The directing and theme is all over the place. It only works as supplemental material to the visual novels, not as standalone work.

Comment: Exactly. If the series followed the amazing style from the first two episodes, it would've been one of the best series out there. Alas, in my opinion, they botched it with the shift.

Answer (score 2):

The first few episodes are flashback of Yui's past. It basically shown what kind of enemy humanity is facing directly and how front lines of humanity's war look. But rest of the show happens in research&development facility far behind enemy lines with team of people who are not concerned with fighting real enemy. The protagonist is actually concerned that he never fought real enemy and all he ever fought were either other humans or simulations. So the dissonance between those two parts actually makes sense.

If you want to experience the full thing, you should read the VNs: [image: How to play MuvLuv]

Comment: Hmm, it seems there's a ton more content to get into - more than I'm likely to do. This might just end up on the wayside until I feel like investing more time.

Comment: Definitely agree that the VN is the way to go here if you have the time. The Muv Luv Alternative VN consistently ranks as one of the best of all time, and has a great deal of content that never made it into the anime.